# How much inappropriate content is there in Dishonored?

Tags: dishonored

I am hoping to get Dishonored for the PC, but there's one thing that's blocking me. My mother and I don't appreciate inappropriate content, so I was hoping someone could tell me how much language and sex there is. Also, is there a way to counter language and sex?

It would be great if someone could answer! I obviously have no game problem and I haven't tried anything yet either. I have a friend who plays Dishonored but he would not give me an answer.

Comment: I would question what you mean by "innapropriate". It is a very vague word. Do you mean no swearing at all? Do you mean occaisional or "low level" swearing is okay? With regards to sex, do you mean specifically scenes of sexual intercourse? Are sexual references okay? What about allusions to sex?

We have no idea what exactly you mean.

Comment: @MichaelCampbell And that is exactly why the ESRB gives a detailed written-out certificate on top of the base rating. (Although, in many cases, the rating and content descriptors that accompany it should be enough.)

Comment: sorry for not adding detail to inappropriate, i mean mild swearing but very little sex, i know there's sex but is there a way to avoid the strippers or whatever they are?

Comment: showing people having sex is not acceptable, mild sexual references are OK, very mild allusions to sex without detail is OK. i have played games with sex such as batman arkham, battlefield 4, and a game where you walk through a place resembling a strip club but thats the limit.

Answer (score 11):

ESRB has a summary of the game based on the rating.  [Click here for a link](http://www.esrb.org/ratings/synopsis.jsp?Certificate=32404).

---

> **Content Descriptors:** Blood and Gore, Intense Violence, Sexual Themes, Strong Language
>
> **Rating Summary:** This is an action game in which players assume the role of Corvo, a royal bodyguard who has been framed for treason (i.e., assassinating an empress). As players help Corvo exact revenge on those who betrayed him, they can use pistols, crossbows, swords, and grenades to kill human enemies in ranged and melee-style combat. Violence is sometimes accompanied by slow-motion effects and gurgling sounds from Corvo's victims. Certain weapons result in dismembered limbs, and attacks are accompanied by exaggerated blood-splatter effects. Some environments depict mutilated corpses on the ground or hanging from the ceiling. During one interactive sequence, Corvo brands a restrained man's cheek with a hot iron; in another, players use electric shocks to interrogate a blindfolded man in a chair. The game depicts some female characters in revealing outfits and includes some sexual/suggestive dialogue (e.g., “Hey sweetheart, you want to play with me? You're a lot cuter than my regulars,” “This one thinks only of whores,” and “Sell your wife into prostitution, I'm sure I can get you a good price.”). The words “f**k,” “sh*t,” and “a*shole” can also be heard in the game.

I haven't played the game, so I have no idea if there is a way to tone-down this content through settings or something.  I'm going to go ahead and guess you can't though, most games don't provide options for that sort of thing.

Comment: Pretty sure you can't turn it off.

Answer (score 3):

In the way of gameplay, you can play the game without killing anyone (avoiding a lot of blood and gore). There's even an achievement / trophy for that: [Clean Hands](http://dishonored.wikia.com/wiki/Clean_Hands).

As for the inappropriate language or sexual content, I believe there is no way you can turn them off. I would say that the place that you mentioned that looks like a strip club (in the '[House of Pleasure](http://dishonored.wikia.com/wiki/House_of_Pleasure)' mission) is still conservative compared to modern standards (and other modern games). There's not much skin shown.

Screenshots:
[image][image][image][image]

---

I found [this method](http://www.reddit.com/r/gaming/comments/135mn2/all_i_want_to_do_after_beating_dishonored_with/c7145qk) of increasing/decreasing the chances of severing limbs (for the PC version). (The post talks about increasing the chances, but modifying the percentage or values would, theoretically, decrease the chances.)

> If you play it on PC, I found that you can increase the chances of limbs being severed upon death (to as much as 100%) by editing the "DishonoredWeapon" file in the following file location:
>
> > C:\Users\**YOU**\Documents\My Games\Dishonored\DishonoredGame\Config"
>
> Make sure you copy/paste the changed contents of "DishonoredWeapon" to "DefaultWeapon" in your Dishonored install directory:
>
> > C:\**PATH VARIES**\Dishonored\DishonoredGame\Config
>
> If you do not do this, the game will return the contents of "DishonoredWeapon" to that of "DefaultWeapon" when you launch the game, overwriting your progress. Backup the original files if you wish to return to standard operation later.
>
> ---
>
> You are looking to change the "m_SeverLimbsUponDeathParams" lines for any weapon you desire.
>
> ---
>
> Change the value for "m_fChanceOfTriggering" in this line to "1" to get 100% limb severing upon killing for the given weapon.
>
> "m_fChanceOfDestroying" determines the chance of each severed limb from gibbing into nothingness as opposed to remaining on the ground.
>
> Changing the value of "m_bExcludeChestBone" to "False" will allow the given weapon to SEVER THE CHEST. This is by far the goriest and most awesome thing about editing this file. Shooting a crossbow bolt at someone's chest will propel their torso, arms, and head (all attached) into a wall...leaving the legs to crumple.
>
> You can even copy the "m_SeverLimbsUponDeathParams" lines to weapon subtitles that were never intended to sever limbs (like the wire trap thing) and change the value of "m_bSeverLimbsUponDeath" to "True". The razorwire trap will cut people to pieces.

<sup>Source: [Comment at Reddit /r/gaming post, "All I want to do after beating Dishonored with low Chaos" by blake_n](http://www.reddit.com/r/gaming/comments/135mn2/all_i_want_to_do_after_beating_dishonored_with/c7145qk)</sup>

Comment: but is it necessary for corvo to go into the golden cat? is it possible to do something like kill the target by getting in through their window?

Comment: to see how inappropriate or appropriate can you paste a picture to show a pic of the golden cat?

Comment: is there a way to avoid guards cussing? also im getting it for the pc

Comment: @user62393 It's necessary for Corvo to go to the Golden Cat, as it is part of a mission's objectives. This is even if you go the stealth, no-killing route. AFAIK, there is no way to prevent NPCs from using inappropriate language, including guards. I'll see what I can find about the screenshot of the Golden Cat and edit it into my answer later.

Comment: @user62393 I've edited in some screenshots of the Golden Cat into my answer.

Comment: can i just go in like a madman and kill them all before any inappropriate content?

Comment: @user62393 Some NPCs in the game will still talk (they're either scripted to do that when you're near them or it could be one of their random dialogues). This makes killing them all before any inappropriate language, hard. But I guess, yeah, you can *lessen* their chances of talking at all if you kill them as soon as you see them. =)